# How do I center an absolute-positioned image with percentage width?

Tags: css

I have an image with the following css:

```
element.style {
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -220px;
    top: 31%;
    width: 440px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I need to change it so that the width is set in percent instead(35.4%). Can I still center it and keep position absolute?

Comment: Bummers... that's sad

Comment: put your html tag also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if you want it the same way as above just use `35.4/2 = 17.7` as your margin ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RPNbR/)):

```
element.style {
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -17.7%;
    top: 31%;
    width: 35.4%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can horizontally center using

```
left:0; right:0; margin:auto;
```

So if you have a div as markup, css would be

```
div
{
    top: 31%;
    width: 38%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt5ca/)**

As long as you have defined a width (in px or % - it doesn't matter) this will work